# Как грамотней организовать хранение слов файле?

Tags: файлы, c++

Как грамотней организовать хранение пяти слов разной длины в файле, которые идут колонками. Т.е., например

```
первый раз слово небо дождь
слово разный длинное снова круг
красный зеленый пять поле часы
```

и тд

И как потом считывать в переменные, например: a b c d e.

Comment: Возможно будет лучше использовать разделитель не встречающийся в словах. Например \x09
Или воспользоваться советами товарища @Gorets 
От себя добавлю: формат CSV

Comment: я вот думаю мож по одному слову в строке и считывать по пять строк? не ...

Comment: Не.

Comment: формат CSV решил проблему. спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если там все будет велформ, то особо без разницы, т.е.

- если ты уверен, что там будут слова разделенные только пробелом, то твой вариант нормальный
- если что-то сложнее лучше оформить в пары - ключ-значение
- если данных много и их надо передавать - лучше сделать json или xml
- если не надо передавать - лучше бд =)